# My own copy() function collides with std::copy()

Tags: c++

I have a header file. In this header I want to use a map for a class. But after I include  I get a `no matching function error`, because I have a copy() function in the project(really big project). I saw on this website http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/download.html that map contains a using std::copy so I guess it collides with that.

I cannot make any changes to the copy function, so is there a way I can use map in this header file ? (no other place). Is there a way so my copy functions don't collide ?

I use Visual Studio 2008 on Windows 7.

Comment: You should post the exact error message, the line (if possible with a bit of context, like types of the objects that appear there) and also whether you have any `using` declaration or directive.

Comment: You aren't actually using the `std::map` implementation from the SGI web site are you? Visual Studio comes with its own implementation of the Standard Library headers and runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message suggests that your function is not visible to the translation unit, so make sure you include the header.

Also, I doubt `<map>` has anything like `using std::copy`. You sure about this one?

In `algobase.h` (which is not standard C++), the `using` directives are parsed only if `__STL_USE_NAMESPACES` is defined. You should undefine it before including the header:

```
#undef __STL_USE_NAMESPACES
#include "algobase.h"
#endif
```

Comment: Well the website that i posted sugests that, but gere at home in Eclipse and Visual Studio 2010 I see diferent thinks, but it is imposibile the funtion to not be visible, because if I remove the #Include <map> everything works fine. I cannot make any modification to the copy function.(I cannot access it)

Comment: @vBx I don't see a `using std::copy` in neither map.h or stl_map.h

Comment: Ahh, sorry, it contains algobase.h witch contains std::copy

Comment: @vBx the using directives are only parsed if `__STL_USE_NAMESPACES` is defined. Are you defining it?

Comment: @vBx I edited, undefining __STL_USE_NAMESPACES before the include should do it.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to wrape the map include in a namespace i.e.

```
    namespace StopCollision
    { #include <map> }
```

Then the map copy function would be available via `StopCollision::std::copy`.  This is very crude, but would solve your problem.

Comment: Plus there's the downside that you need this everywhere you want to include your file. But it's a valid suggestion.

Comment: I agree, in fact I almost did not want to suggest this because I have seen so many people fall into namespace hell when doing similar things.  However, if map really defines std::copy then it would solve his problem.

Comment: I don't quite agree that this is a valid suggestion. The contents of `<map>` are meant to be in the `::std` namespace. Consider if `map` was not a header only library, or if being header only it used a non-header only library. At this point because of your modification in one translation unit you would be using `StopCollision::std::xxx` while the definition would be in `std::xxx` and you would get link errors. Even if you don't your map in this translation unit is not the same (even if defined exactly the same) as a map included in a different translation unit... this leads to the dark path...

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge the map stl class doesn't have a copy function. It is probably an include issue, you could try using a [forward reference](http://www-subatech.in2p3.fr/~photons/subatech/soft/carnac/CPP-INC-1.shtml) to the class that contains the map and copy function.